# updating application scoped data in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, server-push

I have an application with spring with hibernate, and I want to update the Jsp page with this data.
I am updating application scope every time with this class

```
    public class PutDataInApplication implements ServletContextAware{
            int i = 0;
            javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext;
            @Scheduled(fixedDelay=2)
            public void shout(){
                 setServletContext(servletContext);
            }

            @Override
            public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 servletContext.setAttribute("value", i++);
            }

}
```

I want to use this in jsp with this

```
Value is :: ${applicationScope.value}
```

but it showing only `Value is :: 0`
I want to show new data every time. How to do this,i value is incrementing serServletContext() method.
In real I have to call one method in the place of i, but if i show updated i every time i can do that also.
** any use with server - push method **

Answer (score 0):

May be I did not follow your scenario completely. 
But calling

`servletContext.setAttribute("value", i++);`

would just set 0 for attribute named "value" and then increment `i`.

**Begin edit**

Here is what is happening in your code fragment.

1. set `i=0`
2. `shout()` gets called
3. shout calls `setServletContext(..)`
4. overridden `setServletContext(..)` gets called
5. it sets attribute named "value", with value of `i`
6. `i` gets incremented i.e; i=1

Also the behavior you see is not related to spring, it is just that you are using postfix operator ( variable++) in a tricky way.

**End edit**

If you want to see `i` incremented while you call `servletContext.setAttribute` you must use prefix operator ( ++variable)

try
`servletContext.setAttribute("value", ++i);`

Read up on postfix/prefix operators and [check this example program.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/PrePostDemo.java)

Plus each time you are setting the global `i` which is always initialized to 0. Looks like your goal is rather to get integer value of "value" attribute and then increment it.

Comment: if i am printing the i value in the method shout(), it is printing updated i only....

Comment: @RameshK, you seems to be missing basics of the postfix operator. When you print 'i' in shout, it is already incremented inside setSevletContext